# Problems with Netflix in new Google Chrome

Tags: graphics, google-chrome, intel-graphics, amd-graphics

I've been watching Netflix in Google Chrome for months without any problem. Since one of the last updates however, there are weird graphical glitches. If you start a stream, you can only hear the audio. Otherwise the screen remains black or will just show the preview pic, and if you start hovering above the timeline with the mouse, the little thumbnails that pop up will stay. Also, if you scroll down in the menu you get the same effect. It looks like this:

[image]

[image]

I'm using **Google Chrome 50.0.2661.94** (64-bit). So far as I know it is the current version. I have an **i7-6500U CPU** and an **AMD Radeon R5 M335** graphics card. I've tried other videos, they work fine.

Any ideas??!

Comment: I having no trouble with the same version Version 50.0.2661.94 (64-bit). i7 6770hq with Intel 530 graphics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling/enabling the hardware acceleration in Settings /Advanced Settings in Chrome.

See if it's happening in Firefox.

You could also try this: 
http://itsfoss.com/netflix-ubuntu-1404-desktop-app/